# Find overlaps of rows by timedates

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I have data frames like this where min-max are start and end of interval. core_name is name of instance and length_mins is length of interval.

```
                   min                 max length_mins core_name
1  2020-07-28 03:05:30 2020-07-28 05:45:15 159.75 mins       0,1
2  2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-14 16:36:45 127.25 mins      0,10
3  2020-07-16 15:32:45 2020-07-16 16:16:00  43.25 mins      0,11
4  2020-07-17 02:37:30 2020-07-17 05:27:30 170.00 mins      0,11
5  2020-07-18 02:42:00 2020-07-18 05:24:30 162.50 mins      0,11
6  2020-07-25 02:21:15 2020-07-25 04:59:15 158.00 mins      0,12
7  2020-07-16 15:40:15 2020-07-16 16:13:45  33.50 mins      0,13
8  2020-07-16 13:18:30 2020-07-16 16:13:30 175.00 mins      0,15
9  2020-07-16 14:43:00 2020-07-16 15:49:30  66.50 mins       0,2
10 2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-14 16:55:15 145.75 mins       0,4
11 2020-07-16 13:32:45 2020-07-16 17:21:00 228.25 mins       0,6
12 2020-07-27 02:15:30 2020-07-27 05:04:15 168.75 mins       0,6
13 2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-14 16:53:30 144.00 mins       0,8
14 2020-07-16 16:40:30 2020-07-16 21:19:45 279.25 mins       1,0
15 2020-07-14 21:03:15 2020-07-14 22:49:45 106.50 mins       1,1
16 2020-07-15 03:32:45 2020-07-15 06:15:15 162.50 mins      1,10
17 2020-07-16 15:58:15 2020-07-16 21:18:30 320.25 mins      1,10
18 2020-07-14 18:44:00 2020-07-14 20:00:15  76.25 mins      1,11
19 2020-07-14 21:12:00 2020-07-15 00:56:00 224.00 mins      1,11
20 2020-07-16 16:32:30 2020-07-16 19:30:15 177.75 mins      1,12
21 2020-07-14 15:39:15 2020-07-15 00:35:15 536.00 mins      1,13
22 2020-07-16 15:14:15 2020-07-16 21:14:00 359.75 mins      1,14
23 2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-15 00:48:45 619.25 mins      1,15
24 2020-07-16 16:34:00 2020-07-16 20:58:15 264.25 mins      1,16
25 2020-07-14 20:19:15 2020-07-15 00:54:30 275.25 mins      1,17
26 2020-07-16 16:35:00 2020-07-16 21:18:00 283.00 mins      1,18
27 2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-14 19:20:45 291.25 mins      1,19
28 2020-07-14 20:13:00 2020-07-15 01:00:45 287.75 mins      1,19
29 2020-07-16 16:27:45 2020-07-16 21:07:15 279.50 mins       1,2
30 2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-15 00:57:30 628.00 mins       1,3
31 2020-07-16 16:32:30 2020-07-16 21:15:45 283.25 mins       1,4
32 2020-07-14 20:42:15 2020-07-15 00:44:45 242.50 mins       1,5
33 2020-07-16 16:25:00 2020-07-16 21:16:45 291.75 mins       1,6
34 2020-07-14 18:24:00 2020-07-14 23:08:15 284.25 mins       1,7
35 2020-07-16 02:29:30 2020-07-16 05:11:00 161.50 mins       1,7
36 2020-07-16 16:37:45 2020-07-16 21:16:30 278.75 mins       1,8
37 2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-15 00:59:15 629.75 mins       1,9
```

I need to:

1. find rows that overlap each other,
2. calculate number of overlaps,
3. get list of overlapped cores for each core.

Here is a result I receive:

```
                   min                 max length_mins core_name overlaps
1  2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-15 00:59:15 629.75 mins       1,9       15
2  2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-15 00:57:30 628.00 mins       1,3       15
3  2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-15 00:48:45 619.25 mins      1,15       15
4  2020-07-14 15:39:15 2020-07-15 00:35:15 536.00 mins      1,13       15
5  2020-07-16 15:14:15 2020-07-16 21:14:00 359.75 mins      1,14       15
6  2020-07-16 13:32:45 2020-07-16 17:21:00 228.25 mins       0,6       15
7  2020-07-16 15:58:15 2020-07-16 21:18:30 320.25 mins      1,10       14
8  2020-07-14 18:24:00 2020-07-14 23:08:15 284.25 mins       1,7       12
9  2020-07-16 16:25:00 2020-07-16 21:16:45 291.75 mins       1,6       11
10 2020-07-16 16:32:30 2020-07-16 21:15:45 283.25 mins       1,4       11
11 2020-07-16 16:35:00 2020-07-16 21:18:00 283.00 mins      1,18       11
12 2020-07-16 16:27:45 2020-07-16 21:07:15 279.50 mins       1,2       11
13 2020-07-16 16:40:30 2020-07-16 21:19:45 279.25 mins       1,0       11
14 2020-07-16 16:37:45 2020-07-16 21:16:30 278.75 mins       1,8       11
15 2020-07-16 16:34:00 2020-07-16 20:58:15 264.25 mins      1,16       11
16 2020-07-16 16:32:30 2020-07-16 19:30:15 177.75 mins      1,12       11
17 2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-14 19:20:45 291.25 mins      1,19       10
18 2020-07-14 20:13:00 2020-07-15 01:00:45 287.75 mins      1,19       10
19 2020-07-14 20:19:15 2020-07-15 00:54:30 275.25 mins      1,17       10
20 2020-07-14 20:42:15 2020-07-15 00:44:45 242.50 mins       1,5       10
21 2020-07-14 21:12:00 2020-07-15 00:56:00 224.00 mins      1,11       10
22 2020-07-14 21:03:15 2020-07-14 22:49:45 106.50 mins       1,1       10
23 2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-14 16:55:15 145.75 mins       0,4        8
24 2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-14 16:53:30 144.00 mins       0,8        8
25 2020-07-14 14:29:30 2020-07-14 16:36:45 127.25 mins      0,10        8
26 2020-07-16 13:18:30 2020-07-16 16:13:30 175.00 mins      0,15        7
27 2020-07-14 18:44:00 2020-07-14 20:00:15  76.25 mins      1,11        7
28 2020-07-16 15:32:45 2020-07-16 16:16:00  43.25 mins      0,11        7
29 2020-07-16 15:40:15 2020-07-16 16:13:45  33.50 mins      0,13        7
30 2020-07-16 14:43:00 2020-07-16 15:49:30  66.50 mins       0,2        6
31 2020-07-17 02:37:30 2020-07-17 05:27:30 170.00 mins      0,11        1
32 2020-07-27 02:15:30 2020-07-27 05:04:15 168.75 mins       0,6        1
33 2020-07-18 02:42:00 2020-07-18 05:24:30 162.50 mins      0,11        1
34 2020-07-15 03:32:45 2020-07-15 06:15:15 162.50 mins      1,10        1
35 2020-07-16 02:29:30 2020-07-16 05:11:00 161.50 mins       1,7        1
36 2020-07-28 03:05:30 2020-07-28 05:45:15 159.75 mins       0,1        1
37 2020-07-25 02:21:15 2020-07-25 04:59:15 158.00 mins      0,12        1

                                                            cores_list
1  1,9;0,10;0,4;0,8;1,1;1,11;1,11;1,13;1,15;1,17;1,19;1,19;1,3;1,5;1,7
2  1,3;0,10;0,4;0,8;1,1;1,11;1,11;1,13;1,15;1,17;1,19;1,19;1,5;1,7;1,9
3  1,15;0,10;0,4;0,8;1,1;1,11;1,11;1,13;1,17;1,19;1,19;1,3;1,5;1,7;1,9
4  1,13;0,10;0,4;0,8;1,1;1,11;1,11;1,15;1,17;1,19;1,19;1,3;1,5;1,7;1,9
5  1,14;0,11;0,13;0,15;0,2;0,6;1,0;1,10;1,12;1,16;1,18;1,2;1,4;1,6;1,8
6  0,6;0,11;0,13;0,15;0,2;1,0;1,10;1,12;1,14;1,16;1,18;1,2;1,4;1,6;1,8
7      1,10;0,11;0,13;0,15;0,6;1,0;1,12;1,14;1,16;1,18;1,2;1,4;1,6;1,8
8               1,7;1,1;1,11;1,11;1,13;1,15;1,17;1,19;1,19;1,3;1,5;1,9
9                     1,6;0,6;1,0;1,10;1,12;1,14;1,16;1,18;1,2;1,4;1,8
10                    1,4;0,6;1,0;1,10;1,12;1,14;1,16;1,18;1,2;1,6;1,8
11                    1,18;0,6;1,0;1,10;1,12;1,14;1,16;1,2;1,4;1,6;1,8
12                    1,2;0,6;1,0;1,10;1,12;1,14;1,16;1,18;1,4;1,6;1,8
13                    1,0;0,6;1,10;1,12;1,14;1,16;1,18;1,2;1,4;1,6;1,8
14                    1,8;0,6;1,0;1,10;1,12;1,14;1,16;1,18;1,2;1,4;1,6
15                    1,16;0,6;1,0;1,10;1,12;1,14;1,18;1,2;1,4;1,6;1,8
16                    1,12;0,6;1,0;1,10;1,14;1,16;1,18;1,2;1,4;1,6;1,8
17                        1,19;0,10;0,4;0,8;1,11;1,13;1,15;1,3;1,7;1,9
18                        1,19;1,1;1,11;1,13;1,15;1,17;1,3;1,5;1,7;1,9
19                        1,17;1,1;1,11;1,13;1,15;1,19;1,3;1,5;1,7;1,9
20                        1,5;1,1;1,11;1,13;1,15;1,17;1,19;1,3;1,7;1,9
21                        1,11;1,1;1,13;1,15;1,17;1,19;1,3;1,5;1,7;1,9
22                                                 1,1;1,3;1,5;1,7;1,9
23                                 0,4;0,10;0,8;1,13;1,15;1,19;1,3;1,9
24                                 0,8;0,10;0,4;1,13;1,15;1,19;1,3;1,9
25                                 0,10;0,4;0,8;1,13;1,15;1,19;1,3;1,9
26                                    0,15;0,11;0,13;0,2;0,6;1,10;1,14
27                                     1,11;1,13;1,15;1,19;1,3;1,7;1,9
28                                    0,11;0,13;0,15;0,2;0,6;1,10;1,14
29                                    0,13;0,11;0,15;0,2;0,6;1,10;1,14
30                                         0,2;0,11;0,13;0,15;0,6;1,14
31                                                                0,11
32                                                                 0,6
33                                                                0,11
34                                                                1,10
35                                                                 1,7
36                                                                 0,1
37                                                                0,12
```

Here is my code with sample data:

```
# find overlaps

library(dplyr)

library(lubridate)

data.example <-
  structure(
    list(
      min = structure(
        c(
          1595894730,
          1594726170,
          1594902765,
          1594942650,
          1595029320,
          1595632875,
          1594903215,
          1594894710,
          1594899780,
          1594726170,
          1594895565,
          1595805330,
          1594726170,
          1594906830,
          1594749795,
          1594773165,
          1594904295,
          1594741440,
          1594750320,
          1594906350,
          1594730355,
          1594901655,
          1594726170,
          1594906440,
          1594747155,
          1594906500,
          1594726170,
          1594746780,
          1594906065,
          1594726170,
          1594906350,
          1594748535,
          1594905900,
          1594740240,
          1594855770,
          1594906665,
          1594726170
        ),
        tzone = "",
        class = c("POSIXct",
                  "POSIXt")
      ),
      max = structure(
        c(
          1595904315,
          1594733805,
          1594905360,
          1594952850,
          1595039070,
          1595642355,
          1594905225,
          1594905210,
          1594903770,
          1594734915,
          1594909260,
          1595815455,
          1594734810,
          1594923585,
          1594756185,
          1594782915,
          1594923510,
          1594746015,
          1594763760,
          1594917015,
          1594762515,
          1594923240,
          1594763325,
          1594922295,
          1594763670,
          1594923480,
          1594743645,
          1594764045,
          1594922835,
          1594763850,
          1594923345,
          1594763085,
          1594923405,
          1594757295,
          1594865460,
          1594923390,
          1594763955
        ),
        tzone = "",
        class = c("POSIXct",
                  "POSIXt")
      ),
      length_mins = structure(
        c(
          159.75,
          127.25,
          43.25,
          170,
          162.5,
          158,
          33.5,
          175,
          66.5,
          145.75,
          228.25,
          168.75,
          144,
          279.25,
          106.5,
          162.5,
          320.25,
          76.25,
          224,
          177.75,
          536,
          359.75,
          619.25,
          264.25,
          275.25,
          283,
          291.25,
          287.75,
          279.5,
          628,
          283.25,
          242.5,
          291.75,
          284.25,
          161.5,
          278.75,
          629.75
        ),
        class = "difftime",
        units = "mins"
      ),
      core_name = c(
        "0,1",
        "0,10",
        "0,11",
        "0,11",
        "0,11",
        "0,12",
        "0,13",
        "0,15",
        "0,2",
        "0,4",
        "0,6",
        "0,6",
        "0,8",
        "1,0",
        "1,1",
        "1,10",
        "1,10",
        "1,11",
        "1,11",
        "1,12",
        "1,13",
        "1,14",
        "1,15",
        "1,16",
        "1,17",
        "1,18",
        "1,19",
        "1,19",
        "1,2",
        "1,3",
        "1,4",
        "1,5",
        "1,6",
        "1,7",
        "1,7",
        "1,8",
        "1,9"
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,
                  -37L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )

print ( data.example)


data.example <- data.example  %>% mutate (overlaps = 1, cores_list = c(core_name))

print ("Calculating rows overlaps")

for (i in 1:(nrow(data.example)-1)) {
  
  min_el1 <- data.example[i,]$min
  max_el1 <- data.example[i,]$max
  
  for (k in (i+1):nrow(data.example)) {
    
    min_el2 <- data.example[k,]$min
    max_el2 <- data.example[k,]$max
    
    el1_interval <- interval(min_el1, max_el1)
    el2_interval <- interval(min_el2, max_el2)
    overlaps <- int_overlaps(el1_interval, el2_interval)
    
    if (overlaps == T) {
      
      print (paste ("row", i, "overlaps with row", k))
      
      data.example[k,]$overlaps <- data.example[k,]$overlaps +1
      data.example[i,]$overlaps <- data.example[i,]$overlaps +1
      
      
      if ( !grepl( data.example[i,]$cores_list, data.example[k,]$core_name, fixed = TRUE)) {
        data.example[i,]$cores_list <- paste(data.example[i,]$cores_list, data.example[k,]$core_name, sep=';')
      }
      
      if ( !grepl( data.example[k,]$cores_list, data.example[i,]$core_name, fixed = TRUE)) {
        data.example[k,]$cores_list <- paste(data.example[k,]$cores_list, data.example[i,]$core_name, sep=';')
      }
    }
  }
}


data.example <-  data.example %>% arrange(desc(overlaps), desc(length_mins))

print (data.example)
```

I am satisfied with the result but my code is deadly slow. If I have hundreds of rows code takes minutes to run. I am sure using of nested loops can be avoided and code could be significantly speed up. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work.. seems to match desired output..

```
library( data.table )
#make it a data.table
setDT( data.example )
#create temp id column and set is as key (for use with .EACHI later on)
data.example[, id := .I ]
setkey( data.example, id )
#self join on subset by row
data.example[ data.example, 
              c("overlaps", "cores_list") := {
                temp <- data.example[ min <= i.max & max >= i.min, ]
                list( nrow(temp), paste0( temp$core_name, collapse = ";") )
              }, by = .EACHI ]
#if desired, you can drop the id-columns using: data.example[, id := NULL]
```

Comment: Wow. It works at least 100 times faster. Is it best practice to work with such kind of data frames (as in my example) with data.table? Now I usually work with tibble structures and dplyr library.

Comment: `data.table` has become my default waeapon of choice. I also started out using the tidyverse for everything, which can also tackle almost any problem, but `data.table` usually performs faster on larger data. After you get over the 'learning curve'  and have gotten used to the data.table syntax, the readability is almost the same (but do not forget to comment your code ;-) ).